# Proof of reflection principle for harmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

[image]

**My attempt:**

Hi, there! I have known how to prove the above statement when $u\in C^2(U)$, however, I have question about proving the above statement. Because it is $u\in C^2(U^{+}) \cap C(\overline{ U^+})$.

It is really bothering me and I really need help. Thanks a lot.**:)**

Comment: How do you prove when $u\in C^2$ ?

Comment: Hint: The [Mean Value Property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property) is useful here.

Comment: @timur just need to consider the points on $T$. These points are also harmonic because the upper half and the lower half canceled using Mean Value Theorem. So it is proved.

Comment: @timur I am not sure about it.:)

Comment: Yes, if you know about the mean value property, it actually works for continuous functions as well. That is, continuous functions satisfying the mean value property are harmonic, and in particular, automatically smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to verify the mean value property for sufficient small balls for every $x\in \Omega^+ \cup T \cup \Omega^-$. This is clearly true for $x$ such that $x_n>0$, since we start with a function that is harmonic in $\Omega ^+$. By reflection, the function is also harmonic on $\Omega ^-$. Finally, when $x_n=0$, the integral over the upper half ball cancels that over the lower half ball. so we found $U$ is harmonic on the domain $\Omega^+ \cup T \cup \Omega^-$

Comment: So we use the converse mean value property to show that $u$ will be harmonic on $V = \Omega^+ \cup T \cup \Omega^-$. But converse mean value property needs that $u \in C^2(V)$ and we have only $C^1$ on $T$. Do we say that it is $C^2$ almost everywhere?